# Mysqli and binding multiple value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I really don't see what am I doing wrong. The code simply won't write in the table

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // get the form data
            $name = htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $last = htmlentities($_POST['last'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $date = htmlentities($_POST['date'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $ran = htmlentities($_POST['ran'], ENT_QUOTES);

            if ($name == '' || $last == '' || $date == '' || $ran == '')
            {
                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($name, $last, $date, $ran, $error);
            }
            else
            {
                // insert the new record into the database
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT users (name, last, date, ran) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $last, $date, $ran);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                // redirec the user
                header("Location: view.php");
            }

        }
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
        else
        {
            renderForm();
        }

    // close the mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

I have the table ready and if I insert in the table manually it works (I have a View.php) but when I run the form nothing, no error, nothing!

Comment: Does `$stmt->execute()` return `true`? Otherwise print `$stmt->error`

Comment: you wouldn't see the "couldn't bind" error because of the redirect, but if you had warnings enabled it would tell you `could not send headers output already started` try `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of the file

Comment: Warning: mysqli::prepare(): (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1 in ***** on line 74

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`name`,`last`,`date`,`ran`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```